# openerp report with corporate header

Tags: report, odoo

i'm trying to make a report with corporate header but it doesn't work, the report is working fine but i don't have any corporate header, here is my code: 
*report.xml*:

```
<report id="tracker_Labels" 
        model="noc.trajet" 
        name="noc.trajet" 
        string="Tracker Labels" 
        xml="module_coll/report/tracker_label.xml"
        xsl="module_coll/report/tracker_label.xsl" 
        header="True"/>
```

tracker_label.xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
<xsl:import href="../../base/report/corporate_defaults.xsl" />
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:call-template name="rml" />
</xsl:template> <!-- CONTENT -->
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Regards,